# Implement search option for array inside a Json object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, async-await

I want to create a small dictionary with Json and Javascript. Here is my Json file.

```
  {
    "entry": "proud",
    "synonyms": ["noble", "illustrious"],
  }
]
```

So the user should be able to search the entry (ie., proud) or any one of the synonym (noble or illustrious) and get the results.

My JS

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
async function findWords(){
    const res = await fetch('./dict.json');
    const data = await res.json();

    data.filter(function(item){
        if(input.value === item.entry){
            console.log(item.entry);
            console.log(item.synonyms);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing at the moment? Note `filter` returns a new array.

Comment: What is `search.value`? Did you mean `input.value`?